# How to tell emacs/etags to ignore errors if any of the file in tags-table-list is invalid?

Tags: emacs, etag

I use `(setq tags-table-list <> <> .. <>)` (in ~/.emacs) to tell emacs/etags to look for TAGS files in the directories mentioned. Some of these directories are not always present or mounted. So whenever I search for any tag, emacs will throw error saying *"File <> is not a valid tags table"*. Is there anyway to tell emacs to ignore that file and proceed looking in other directories ?

Update:
In continuation to the previous question, is there any way to tell `emacs` to ignore the `TAGS` files which are existing but not in valid format ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the files upon startup:

```
(require 'cl)
(setq tags-table-list (remove-if (lambda (elt) (not (file-exists-p elt))) 
                                 '("path1" "/dev/null" "~/.emacs" "dude")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `file-exists-p` as shown [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/Testing-Accessibility.html).  The same function works for directories too.